# I need to populate an array with the information from an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

The array is two dimensional. I'm able to read the information from the excel file. That much I have accomplished; but I can't figure out how to write the code to populate the array I have created. I cannot hard code the data because there is over two 2000 entries. I need the array so I can use the information from the excel file to plug into the formula in the rest of my program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            string str;
            int rCnt;
            int cCnt;
            int rw = 0;
            int cl = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\data.csv", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            rw = range.Rows.Count;
            cl = range.Columns.Count;

            decimal[,] coords = new decimal[2207,2];


            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it required to use Array only? can you use List instead ?

Comment: If you have CSV file, you better use simpler API of CSV readers than full Excel interop functionality. Check [Josh Close CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library with [reading examples](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#getting-all-records) there

Comment: I could use anything that I saw fit.  I've never used a list, so an array was just my go to.  Also, I need to take the array (or w/e I use to store the information read from the excel file) and plug it into a formula to determine all the peaks and valleys of the coords, so I just figured an array was the simplest thing to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
rw = range.Rows.Count;
cl = range.Columns.Count;

decimal[,] coords = new decimal[rw,cl]; // not hardcoded size

for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
    {
        coords[rCnt-1, cCnt-1] = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value;
    }
}
```

---

Note that if your two columns are related, you could do something like that:

```
public class Coord
{
    public decimal X {get;set;}
    public decimal Y {get;set;}
}
```

and then:

```
rw = range.Rows.Count;

List<Coord> coords = new List<Coord>();

for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    coords.Add(new Coord
    {
        X = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value,
        Y = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 2].Value,
    });
}
```